# JApplet ClassNotFoundException with any applet

Tags: java, html, classnotfoundexception, japplet

I am writing an applet in Eclipse. It does work in the JApplet viewer. However, when I try to make ANY applet run in ANY browser I get the ClassNotFound exception.
For example:

```
import javax.swing.JApplet;


public class TestApplet extends JApplet
{
public void init()
{
    this.setSize(800, 600);
    this.setVisible(true);
}
public void start()
{

}

}
```

This launches in the applet viewer.
When embedded in this code,

```
<html>
<body>
<applet code = "TestApplet.class">
<applet>
</body>
</htmL>
```

I get the above mentioned error. The applet is in the same folder as the webpage. Tested it on 2 different computers.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: BTW - do you realize that applet does absolutely nothing that is useful?  The override of `start()` is pointless, since the new method does nothing.  Of the two statements in the `init()` method, the first is something that should not be done, and the 2nd happens automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That HTML is not valid.

I wish programmers would realize that throwing 'any old crap' together does not result in valid HTML.  Mark-up needs to be validated.  One way to validate it is to use the [W3C Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/).

Once that is sorted, note that it might still have problems.  Ensure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show for applets & copy/paste any output.